# Alternative methods to GPS for finding & transmitting a device's physical location?

Tags: gps, location

I'm trying to research the most minimal methods of transmitting a device's (not a phone's) physical location with a high degree of accuracy. Other than GPS, what options do I have?

Comment: How high a degree and do you have anything else to use than the "device?

Comment: To within 2-3 metres? And sorry, a *small* portable transmitter/receiver

Answer (score 2):

Well this might be a bit complicated but it was produced by my college so here

http://www.cylab.cmu.edu/files/pdfs/mobility/Wi_Fi_Locationing_2008.pdf

This talks about locating people using WiFi using room-level accuracy. I never got to reading the whole thing but it has proved useful to me in my research.

Answer (score 2):

Would depend on what the device transmits receives, but you could use RSSI values. this is widely used with different RF-protocols. You triangulate the location by comparing LQI/RSSI (Signal Strengt) values to different beacons. Wifi routers, Zigbee coordinators, RFID antennas.

Comment: How accurate is this method?

Comment: Depends on hardware and amount of beacons. but with infinite amount of beacons, it's theoretically pinpoint. But with 2 beacons per room. you can know on which side of the room the device is.